# How to check if I have a rogue SSL/TLS certificate?

Tags: tls, certificates, windows, man-in-the-middle

It's known, that if someone manages to install their certificate as a trusted certificate on your Windows computer, they can read all you SSl/TLS traffic with man-in-the-middle attack and you won't notice.

Is there a simple practical way of determining, if you have any of those certificates installed? When you look at your certificate store, there are a lot of certificates there, and most of them are legitimate ones. How can one tell which ones are "ok" and which ones may represent a security risk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RCC](http://trax.x10.mx/apps.html) or [Sigcheck](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897441.aspx) will do that for you. 
RCC checks the Firefox root store too.

Answer (score 1):

You may take a list you find apropriate - for example [the CAs Mozilla comes preinstalled with](https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA:IncludedCAs) - and check your trust store.

For extra tin foil, remove all and readd them from the list when you encounter a site that is untrusted but should be trusted;)

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Manually checking one by one is not what I'd call practical. But thank you anyway.

Comment: Stupid question, but how do you remove them, and re-add them all securely? (Without using a second, trusted, computer.)